# Inserting an array as field in existing element

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code:

```
$user_array = array("user"=>$user);
$user_array["user"]["groups"] = $groups;
$user_details = new Collection($user_array);
```

I'm using Laravel and trying to add a users groups as a element into the user. This actually works but I'm looking for something a bit more elegant than this. Basically I want to add the $groups array to the $user array as another field.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Hi @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi Thanks for the response. The issue is not with the relationships. I have these. What I'm looking for is to take the information returned and adding it to one array. I hope this makes sense.
I'm getting the groups as a belongsToMany call so I just want to get the user with all their groups for the API I'm creating. Again this is working but I feel there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to convert $user to an array. Because $user is not an array.

```
$user = $user->toArray();
```

After you can append your groups to the created array.

```
$user_array = array("user"=>$user);
$user_array["user"]["groups"] = $groups;
$user_details = new Collection($user_array);
```